# Cant append HTML structre in jQuery PHP WORDPRESS

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

    $("td").filter(function (){
        return $(this).text() == '<?php echo $eventDate ?>';
    }).css({ 'background-color': 'Green' });


    $("td").filter(function (){
        return $(this).text() == '<?php echo $eventDate ?>';
    }).append("
    <div id="myCard" class="flip-container" >
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                <!-- front content -->
                salam
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <!-- back content -->
                salam
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>");


});
</script>
```

Comment: You can't use a string multiline like that in JavaScript. Check your syntax here http://www.jshint.com/ to see if it's valid.

Comment: Thank u pal :) so how can i add this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the double quotes, you need to escape them or use single ones to wrap the html:

```
$("td").filter(function (){
    return $(this).text() == '<?php echo $eventDate ?>';
}).append('
<div id="myCard" class="flip-container" >
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <!-- front content -->
            salam
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            <!-- back content -->
            salam
        </div>
    </div>
</div>');
```

Also, you cannot use multi-lines like that in javascript (the example above is just to illustrate the quotes).

I would build the dom in jquery as you are using it, but you could also escape the new-lines and then the combined result would be:

```
$("td").filter(function (){
    return $(this).text() == '<?php echo $eventDate ?>';
}).append('<div id="myCard" class="flip-container" > \
    <div class="flipper"> \
        <div class="front"> \
            <!-- front content --> \
            salam \
        </div> \
        <div class="back"> \
            <!-- back content --> \
            salam \
        </div> \
    </div> \
</div>');
```

Comment: Thank you Jeroen. This has saved me a lot of time.  :)